# npx cannot find module 'webpack'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, npx

I'm trying to test a custom Webpack configuration. I've read that instead of typing `node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`, I can use `npx webpack`. But I can't seem to get it to work.

```
user@comp:~/raw> npx webpack
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D
```

When I switch to running `npx webpack-cli`, I get a different error:

```
user@comp:~/> npx webpack-cli
npx: installed 489 in 19.186s
Cannot find module 'webpack'
```

Comment: Have you installed both webpack and webpack-cli?

Comment: Can you double-check if you're in a directory with a `package.json` (or that Webpack is installed globally and linked)?

Comment: The instructions on the first error message say precisely what you should do here: `npm install webpack-cli -D`. Reading error messages is important 

Comment: To clarify: the binary itself is still `webpack` (and not `webpack-cli`), you just have to have the `webpack-cli` package installed.

Comment: Running `npm install webpack-cli -D` does not fix the problem.

Comment: After running that command, you get this error: `Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'`

Comment: You can try `npx -p webpack-cli webpack`

Answer (score 1):

```
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D
```

Basically that's all. After you've installed the webpack-cli just use

```
npx webpack
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install webpack and webpack-cli packages globally so you won't need to use `node ./path/to/webpack` :

```
  $ npm install webpack webpack-cli -g
```

This will install webpack globally on your machine. Then in your project folder run

```
  $ webpack
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice in the other answers and installed Webpack globally with `npm install webpack webpack-cli -g`.

When I ran `npx webpack`, I got

```
No configuration file found and no output filename configured via CLI option.
A configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory.
Use --help to display the CLI options.
```

That's when I realized that I wasn't in the project folder...

Comment: That's what I suspected 

Answer (score -1):

I tried to install `webpack-cli` again and it worked

Comment: It is a good idea to post an answer if you have  a different solution.